# Default read and connection timeouts for reactor-netty HttpClient

Tags: java, httpclient, reactor-netty

I know that a read and a connection timeouts can be configured in reactor-netty HttpClient, like:

```
  public WebClient xsdWebClient() {

    HttpClient httpClient = createHttpClient(config.getConnectionTimeout(), config.getReadTimeout());

    return WebClient.builder()
        .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient.followRedirect(true)))
        .baseUrl(config.getHost())
        .build();
  }

  private static HttpClient createHttpClient(int connectionTimeout, int readTimeout) {
    return HttpClient.create()
        .option(
            ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS,
            (int) TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(connectionTimeout))
        .doOnConnected(c -> c.addHandlerLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(readTimeout)));
  }
```

But what are the default read and connection timeouts for reactor-netty HttpClient?

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you to use the [response timeout](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/api/reactor/netty/http/client/HttpClient.html#responseTimeout-java.time.Duration-) configuration provided by Reactor Netty instead of `ReadTimeoutHandler`. You can configure the response timeout either globally on `HttpClient` level for all requests or per request.
The default values for various timeouts provided by Reactor Netty you can find in the [reference documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/reference/index.html#_timeout_configuration).

Comment: What about TcpClient's default connect, read and write timeouts? Documentations says nothing about it.

Answer (score 2):

Referring to [answer](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/26#issuecomment-276625982) given by one of the devs of `reactor-netty`, the read default time is 10 seconds.